# How to show that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)(x+c) }}=\frac{2K(-\frac{1}{c})}{\sqrt{c}}$?

Tags: calculus, elliptic-integrals

From WolframAlpha or Mathematica
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)(x+c) }}=\frac{2K(-\frac{1}{c})}{\sqrt{c}}$$ for $c>0$
where
$$K(x)$$
was the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

However, I could not find out where does this expression come from.
How to show that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)(x+c) }}=\frac{2K(-\frac{1}{c})}{\sqrt{c}}$?

Comment: Try this substitution $x = u^2$, before, change $(x+c)$ by $c(\frac{x}{c}+1)$

Comment: The substitution $x=u^2$ does the job perfectly. It appears you made some mistake while using the substitution. Please show your work so that the mistake can be figured out. Also note that as per Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha we have $K(x) =\int_0^1\frac{du}{\sqrt{(1-u^2)(1-xu^2)}}$ so that $x$ is the parameter (usually denoted by $m$) and not modulus (usually denoted by $k$).